# Как взять все, кроме конкретного контейнера с class?

Tags: css, css3, css-selectors

```html
<div class="some">
  <span class="some1">1231231</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span class="some1">asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <div>asdasd</div>
</div>

<div class="some">
  <span class="some1">1231231</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span class="some1">asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
</div>
```

Как взять весь контент в класе `some` кроме `some1`?

Comment: У вас небольшое противоречие: заголовок вопроса про атрибут `id`,  а тело вопроса — про `class`.

Comment: исправил спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```css
.some *:not(.some1) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="some">
    <span class="some1">1231231</span>
    <span>asdasd</span>
    <span class="some1">asdasd</span>
    <span>asdasd</span>
    <div>asdasd</div>
  </div>

  <div class="some">
    <span class="some1">1231231</span>
    <span>asdasd</span>
    <span class="some1">asdasd</span>
    <span>asdasd</span>
  </div>

  <body>
```

Подробнее о `:not()` - [тут](https://webref.ru/css/not).